# Why does GCC not attempt memory leak checking?

Tags: c, memory-management, gcc, memory-leaks

While I rarely use C anymore, I was thinking about the rule I was always told that "if you call `malloc()` (or `new`), you must call `free()` (or `delete`)". It brought me to wondering if GCC (or another C compiler) attempts to perform any kind of memory and warn the user of a potential issue. I never heard about it, so I suspected it wasn't the case, but I wanted to find out.

Here's the example I used:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int* first = malloc(sizeof(int) *  10);
  int* second = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

  int i = 0;
  for (; i < 10; i++) {
    first[i] = i * 2;
    second[i] = i * 10;
  }

  free(first);  /* Forgot to free second */
  return 0;
}
```

When compiling with `gcc -Wall free_test.c` no warnings were generated. While I can see why the compiler cannot provide a perfect answer because you're dealing with heap memory and managing this at run time, why does the compiler not appear to attempt to provide a warning that there could be a memory leak?

Some of my thoughts on why include:

1. The compiler may not have a perfect way of telling when memory is freed. For example, if one of those pointers was passed into a function and freed from within the function, the compiler may not be able to tell that.
2. If a different thread takes ownership of the memory, the compiler would not have any way to tell that somebody else could be freeing memory.

Comment: The problem is that this is a runtime issue, compilers can't detect things like memory leaks. For example, just because I don't free a pointer right away doesn't mean that some other chunk of code much later won't free it.

Comment: No, I suppose it's not. It was just something I was curious about (since I would imagine it could be possible) to throw a warning indicating a problem may exist.

Comment: Even modern compilers like the C# compiler can't check for this. They rely on runtime constructs like a garbage collector to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cases that can't be detected via static analysis (let alone via trivial static analysis) vastly outnumber those that can.  The compiler authors presumably decided the benefits of adding this extra complexity to GCC was outweighed by the costs.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more complex than counting the `free` and `malloc` calls. Imagine a library, where some library functions assume that the library calls `malloc`, but assumes that the user of the library will call `free`.

Comment: I think GCC should ideally provide some attribute to mark such functions accordingly as ones that transfer ownership of a dynamically allocated memory to a user.

Answer (score 0):

GCC has a special `-fanalyze` mode [which does a number of different checks](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html), including for `malloc` leaks.

For demonstration purposes I had to modify your code to move into a separate `foo()` function, because when it's in `main()`, the malloc complaint was missing. I presume GCC assumes that returning from main will free the memory anyway. I also had to add a `-Wno-analyzer-possible-null-dereference` to silence a warning about the result of `malloc()` possibly being `NULL` *(to avoid unnecessarily modifying the code from the question)*.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo() {
  int* first = malloc(sizeof(int) *  10);
  int* second = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);

  int i = 0;
  for (; i < 10; i++) {
    first[i] = i * 2;
    second[i] = i * 10;
  }

  free(first);  /* Forgot to free second */
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  return foo();
}
```

Result:

```hs
 λ gcc test.c -o a -fanalyzer -Wno-analyzer-possible-null-dereference                  
test.c: In function ‘foo’:
test.c:14:10: warning: leak of ‘second’ [CWE-401] [-Wanalyzer-malloc-leak]
   14 |   return 0;
      |          ^
  ‘foo’: events 1-9
    |
    |    5 |   int* second = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    |      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |                 |
    |      |                 (1) allocated here
    |......
    |    8 |   for (; i < 10; i++) {
    |      |          ~~~~~~  
    |      |            |
    |      |            (2) following ‘true’ branch (when ‘i <= 9’)...
    |      |            (5) following ‘true’ branch (when ‘i <= 9’)...
    |      |            (7) following ‘false’ branch (when ‘i > 9’)...
    |    9 |     first[i] = i * 2;
    |      |          ~       
    |      |          |
    |      |          (3) ...to here
    |      |          (6) ...to here
    |   10 |     second[i] = i * 10;
    |      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |               |
    |      |               (4) assuming ‘second’ is non-NULL
    |......
    |   13 |   free(first);  /* Forgot to free second */
    |      |   ~~~~~~~~~~~    
    |      |   |
    |      |   (8) ...to here
    |   14 |   return 0;
    |      |          ~       
    |      |          |
    |      |          (9) ‘second’ leaks here; was allocated at (1)
```